# Counting vowels in an array

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, nested

I know I'm close to figuring this out but I've been wracking my brain and can't think of what's going wrong here. I need to count the number of vowels in the array of `nameList` using the `vowelList` array, and currently it's outputting 22, which is not the correct number of vowels.

Incidentally, 22 is double the length of the array nameList, but I can't see any reason what I wrote would be outputting double the array length. Any help would be appreciated. Not looking for the answer, for a nudge in the right direction.

```
nameList = [ "Euclid", "Archimedes", "Newton","Descartes", "Fermat", "Turing", "Euler", "Einstein", "Boole", "Fibonacci", "Nash"]
vowelList = ['A', 'a', 'E', 'e', 'I', 'i', 'O', 'o', 'U','u']

z=0
counter = 0
for k in nameList:
    i = 0
    for q in vowelList:
        counter+=nameList[z].count(vowelList[i])
        i+=1
    z=+1
print("The number of vowels in the list is",counter)
```

Comment: You're reusing the variable `k`. Choose a different name.

Comment: @MattDMo I've fixed that, and I still get the same result. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I gotta say, that inner loop is one of the oddest constructs I've seen in a while. `q` is already set to `vowelList[i]` every time. Same as `k` with `nameList[z]`.

Comment: what `code editor` are you using ?

Comment: I'm using PyCharm Edu @moctarjallo

Comment: I'm voting to close as a typo: change `z = +1` to `z += 1` and your code is fine.

Comment: I found this through basic debugging: when you print `nameList[z]` at each iteration, you see that it's adding the vowels in `Archimedes` over and over.

Comment: @MadPhysicist wow, you're absolutely correct. All the same, I really appreciate all the comments and replies that were made - they helped me understand how to more effectively use Python loops.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm going to leave my close vote because it's technically correct, but not going to downvote because it's a tough one to puzzle out. Hopefully you learned something about debugging too :)

Comment: @wombatpandaa okay so this means you can launch the **debugger** on PyCharm and see what is going on !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're thinking about this too hard. Relax and let Python do the work:

```
nameList = [ "Euclid", "Archimedes", "Newton","Descartes", "Fermat", "Turing", "Euler", "Einstein", "Boole", "Fibonacci", "Nash"]
nameStr = ''.join(nameList).lower()
nVowels = len([c for c in nameStr if c in 'aeiou'])
print(f"The number of vowels in the list is {nVowels}.")
>>> The number of vowels in the list is 31.
```

Plenty of ways to skin a cat in Python :)

Comment: This doesn't explain the error in the code. OP's code is fine up to a typo. Aside from the odd loops, I'd say it's pretty legible and pythonic too

Comment: True true! I would only add that (IMO) lengthy code with lots of aliases creates more opportunities for that sort of mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something more comprehensible:

```
nameList = [ "Euclid", "Archimedes", "Newton","Descartes", "Fermat", "Turing", "Euler", "Einstein", "Boole", "Fibonacci", "Nash"]
vowelList = ['A', 'a', 'E', 'e', 'I', 'i', 'O', 'o', 'U','u']


counter = 0
for name in nameList:
    for char in name:
        for vowel in vowelList:
            if char == vowel:
                counter += 1
print("The number of vowels in the list is",counter)
```

`The number of vowels in the list is 31`

Comment: IMO this is quite a bit less comprehensible than OP's two loops. Using the `in` operator would help you get rid of a loop without sacrificing legibility.

Comment: I meant more comprehensible than the answer they were given. Otherwise I would've suggested the one-liner `sum(i in 'aeiouAEIOU' for j in nameList for i in j)`

Comment: I would wrap that string in a `set`.